# spring boot jpa manyToOne(column="fatherId") join the same entity works on a recursive way until the fatherId is null

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
Entity{
    String code;
    String parentCode;
...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parentCode",referencedColumnName="code")
    Entity parentEntity;
}
```

My entity class is like this. what i want to do is using findAll() to get an entity list with each entity get its own direct parent. But spring jpa will get parent's parent until the root , i need to avoid this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not about Spring JPA but JPA itself. When you add a relationship, following defaults apply unless specified otherwise.

`@xxToOne` - `FetchType.EAGER`

`@xxToMany`- `FetchType.LAZY`

So, in your example you have a `@ManyToOne` which has a default `EAGER` fetch and one join query is appended. If your parent has another `@xxToOne` it adds one more join and so on. It's good to know the boundaries of your entities and decide which type of `FetchType` is required.

Even if you add like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="parentCode",referencedColumnName="code")
Entity parentEntity;
```

.. if you parent has more relationships you might be getting everything loaded while fetching parent. Thus, all relationships need to be Lazy. It's a design choice based on entities.

But be aware about the ORM's **N+1 problem** : [JPA Hibernate n+1 issue (Lazy & Eager Diff)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513449/jpa-hibernate-n1-issue-lazy-eager-diff)

Comment: i hope this work ,but it seems not. I still get the infinite recursivion until fatherId is null

Answer (score 0):

Since a default fetch type for a `@ManyToOne` relation is an `FetchType.EAGER` I think you have just add a fetch type as `LAZY` explicitly:

```
Entity{
    String code;
    String parentCode;
...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parentCode",referencedColumnName="code")
    Entity parentEntity;
}
```